# Code to enable depth map-generated perspective change from a single image?

Tags: ios, image-processing, depth

I have a question about the algorithm used in DEPTHY, the iOS app. This uses the depth map generated through the dual lenses of the iPhone to enable changing the perspective of an image (wobbling). This is presumably an application of DIBR (depth image-based rendering).

Anyone know if there is open source code or even commercial libraries to create frames based on an initial image and a depth map that could be used for generation in iOS?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you watch the relevant WWDC 2017 videos?

Comment: Thanks for the response - yes, I've been through those and understand about the generation of the depth map, how to access it, extract it from the image etc. - but that only relates to the depth map. My question is about using the depth map to generate a different perspective of the image

Comment: OK, understood. I knew only that they went into quite a bit of depth (no pun intended).

Comment: FYI a relevant WWDC17 video relating to depth maps is: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/507/